# Atrai vs Flexlm License for ClearCase Server 7.1.2

Tags: clearcase

I have installed a ClearCase server and license server along with license key administrator.

Now I need to apply the license to license server so that I can point to license server from license key Adminstrator and get my licenses.

Now my question is what type of license I should use? 
That is, Atria or Flexlm? 
Which one is right one? 
And what is the difference between these two type of licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would know if you are using flexlm licensing, since the technote "[How to switch between Atria and FLEXlm licensing on UNIX and Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21283862)" shows a clear naming convention:

> Copy the `flexlm_host.template` file (located in one of the following directories) to the `/var/adm/rational/clearcase/config` directory

The difference:

- Atria is the legacy licensing system for ClearCase.
- Flexlm is the more recent licensing system, applied for *all* Rational products.
  If you have more than ClearCase to support, Flexlm is certainly more appropriate.

[This thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014012579#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014013601) summarizes the advantages of one over another:

> The primary advantage of FlexLM over classic is that you can license exclusively to a group of users
>
> A single ClearCase user should only need 1 non-temporary Flex/LM license
>   to access ClearCase.
>
> If you are using Temporary ClearCase Licenses, use Atria licenses to avoid
>   issues.
>   If you are using Permanent licenses, use whatever type you want.